# Override string prototype function not compiling in angular lib

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-library, ng-packagr

**string-prototype.service.ts**

```js
String.prototype.equals = equals;
String.prototype.includes = includes;

interface String {
  equals: typeof equals;
  includes: typeof includes;
}

function equals(a):boolean {
  if(typeof (a) !== "string"){
    a = a.toString();
  }
  return this.toLowerCase() == a.toLowerCase();
}

function includes(searchString:string, position?:number):boolean {
  let stringS:any = searchString;
  if(typeof (stringS) !== "string"){
    searchString = stringS.toString();
  }
  let k = this.toLowerCase().match(searchString.toLowerCase());
  if (position && k) {
    return k.index === position;
  }
  return !!k;
}
```

Now I import the ts file into the library module
**angular-****.module.ts**

```js
import { DataTableComponent } from './data-table/data-table.component';
import {DragDropModule} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import { ClickOutsideModule } from 'ng4-click-outside';
import './string-prototype.service.ts';
```

Now I used the string prototype function in **data-table.component** in my angular app it is working fine. But after I convert into angular library and when I build the library I got a error below:

```js
BUILD ERROR
projects/angular-***-***/src/lib/data-table/data-table.component.ts(296,75): error TS2339: Property 'equals' does not exist on type 'String'.

Error: projects/angular-***-***/src/lib/data-table/data-table.component.ts(296,75): error TS2339: Property 'equals' does not exist on type 'String'.

    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\Angular 7\Library\angular-***-***-lib\node_modules\ng-packagr\lib\ngc\compile-source-files.js:65:19)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (D:\Projects\Angular 7\Library\angular-***-***-lib\node_modules\ng-packagr\lib\ngc\compile-source-files.js:4:58)
```

How to resolve the error. The strange thing is for the app it is working fine. But in the case of Lib, it is not compiling.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: anything to do with ES-target version? something like this in the settings? https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/docs/language-level.md